# mongoDB cant Import a CSV files

Tags: mongodb, import, mongoimport

I am trying to import a CSV file to MongoDB following this command:

```
mongoimport -d Northwind -c "employee-territories" --type csv --file "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/northwind-mongo-master/employee-territories.csv" --headerline
```

but I've got the following error message

```
"Syntax Error: missing ; before statement (shell):1"
```

to solve this error I have to use `mongoimport` OUTSIDE the `mongoshell` environment.

So I just turn  `terminal` on

Unfortunately I've got the error message

```
error inserting documents: not authorized on Northwind to execute command { insert: "employee-territories", writeConcern: { getLastError: 1, w: 1 }, ordered: false, $db: "Northwind" }
```

what's wrong with my code ?? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your reply, But after adding `the user name` and `password` the following error appeared

```
" Failed: error connecting to db server: server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed "
```

To resolve this error I added `--host` and  `--authenticationDatabase` parameters and it worked while we connecting to a remote MongoDB

Use the similar below format in your code:

```
 mongoimport --host 127.0.0.1:27017 -u "admin" -p "admin123" --authenticationDatabase admin  -d Northwind -c "employee-territories" --type csv --file "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/northwind-mongo-master/employee-territories.csv" --headerline
```

Answer (score 7):

Looks like, that you forgot to provide the authentication data (username, password and authenticationDatabase).

Your command should look like that:

```
mongoimport -u "your username" -p "yoyr password" --authenticationDatabase "admin" -d Northwind -c "employee-territories" --type csv --file "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/northwind-mongo-master/employee-territories.csv" --headerline
```

Take a look into [mongoimport documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#required-access).